# how to check if custom post title exists or not?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have written functionality for checking if custom post title exists or not while adding post. like below:

```
  function wp_exist_post_by_title( $title ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $return = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT ID FROM wp_dxwe_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $title . "' && post_status = 'publish' && post_type = 'courses' ", 'ARRAY_N' );
    if( empty( $return ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

While adding new post my code is below:

```
$check = $this->wp_exist_post_by_title( $_POST['course_title']  ) ;
if($check==true)
{
  $title = '';
  echo "<div class='conditional-messages'>Course Already Exists !</div>";
}
else 
{
  $title=$_POST['course_title'];
}   
$post = array(
             'post_title'   => $title,
             'post_content'  => $description,
             'post_status'  => 'publish', 
             'post_type'    => "courses"  
            );  
$description = $_POST['description'];
$id = wp_insert_post($post);
update_post_meta($id, 'course_icon', $attachement_id);
update_post_meta( $id, 'inistitute_name', $institute_name);
```

While I am adding new post(course title) it is checking if post_title exists or not perfectly but my problem here is I want to check post title(course title) belongs to only one 'institute_name' because other institutes can have the same course title(custom post) too. I know I need to join 2 tables i.e. 'wp_posts' & 'wp_postmeta', but I was unable to do. can anyone please tell me how to sort out this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you prefixing *your own* function with `wp_`? That's worse than having no prefix at all.

Comment: @toscho, sorry one of our past developer kept like that but is there any problem if I put like that?

Comment: If WordPress ever decides to implement a new function, it will very likely use the prefix `wp_`. That's the only prefix you absolutely cannot use in your own code. :)

Comment: @toscho, got it, I renamed that function name. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
if (get_page_by_title('Some Title', OBJECT, 'post_type')) {
    // Exists
}
```

**post_type** can be "post", "page", a custom post type slug, etc.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title

Comment: It will also return the draft and trash post.

Answer (score 1):

Using post_exists() function, you can find out if any of your posts have a certain title.

[Code Reference post_exists()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/)

From comments by "Amirhosseinhpv"

> check if post exist by title :
>
> ```
> $found_post = post_exists( "My Post Title",'','','');
> echo $found_post ? "Found post at id #$found_post" : "Can't find post!";
> ```
>
> Check if custom post type [news] exist by title :
>
> ```
> $found_post = post_exists( "My Post Title",'','','news');
> echo $found_post ? "Found post at id #$found_post" : "Can't find post!";
> ```

You need to include 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' if you performing the check on the frontend as following:

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );